# Trigger.io: Splash screen shows too long when opening

Tags: optimization, splash-screen, trigger.io

In our application, it has only js files, one index.html file, and one ajax request for our initial  load, well and some images for our application.

But it takes 7 seconds for the splash image to hide.

Are there any way where we can optimize the loading time of our application? Or can we manually bring down the loading time of the splash screen?

Thanks!

regards,
Junnel

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`forge.launchimage.hide` API](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html#hide), you can clear the launchimage when you want - when your app is "ready enough" to be shown to the user.

We hide the launchimage image automatically on the window load event, or after 5 seconds, whichever comes first.